# Submitting multiple jobs at once in DataBricks

Tags: jobs, azure-databricks

I have a DataBricks notebook which takes the date as input parameter, and which runs as a daily job.

Now I need to have it run for a number of past days, but launching the job manually with a custom date is quite tedious.

Is there an easy way to run a batch of jobs in one shot, e.g. from another notebook (within a loop on the date range) ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the API allows to [run an existing job](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#run-now), using the cluster already defined for the job¹.

Launching a job with parameters is as simple as

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <your_token>" -X POST https://<your_databricks_instance_url>/api/2.0/jobs/run-now -d '{"job_id": <ID>, "notebook_params": { "param1": "value1", … } }'
```

so it’s straightforward to launch a batch of jobs from bash or whatever.

Tokens are generated in the User Settings.

¹ Having to create a cluster through the API was my fear, since we use environment variables, libraries and initialization scripts.  However when editing the cluster properties on the DataBricks web interface, one can apparently retrieve all these parameters at once by clicking on the "JSON" link, and I guess it can be used to feed the API.